# Как защититься от psh ack flood по tcp?

Tags: linux, tcp, iptables, ddos

Мой сервер атакуют множеством пакетов tcp с флагами push ack. Как защититься от такой атаки?

У меня debain 9.
Я делал tcpdump и там хорошо видно, этих пакетов просто дофига, трафик во время атаки примерно 400-800 мегабайт в секунду:
[image: tcpdump]

В общем в типе атаке я уверен, но как лучше защититься? Ведь это нормальные флаги, они могут встречаться и в обычных соединениях.

Спасибо заранее за советы.

И прокомментируйте пожалуйста эту мысль: а флаг psh вообще действительно необходим? Возможно его просто стоит удалять из заголовка пакета? К чему это может привести?

Comment: Программная защита в системе никак не спасёт от физической перегрузки канала в сетевой карте.

Comment: @andreymal надеюсь, что все же как-то можно. иначе моему проекту не выжить. хотябы снизить воздействие

Comment: Единственный способ спастись от перегрузки канала мусорным трафиком — сделать так, чтобы мусорный трафик вообще не дошёл до сервера. Обычно это подразумевает подключение какого-нибудь Cloudflare

Comment: @andreymal ну у меня ovh хост, там anti ddos ovh. но все же пропускает он такую атаку. cloudflare, ddos-guard стоят минимум 100-300$, мне это близко не подходит. если и можно сделать хоть что-то со стороны linux, я хочу это сделать.
я понял вашу мысль про нагрузку канала. но что если это из-за того, что я весь трафик пропускаю беспрепятственно? если его отбросить на ранних этапах, по идее должно быть легче.. вопрос в этом и заключается. как отличить плохой трафик от хорошего, флаги psh ack встречаются и в обычных соединениях..

Comment: помимо забивки канала трафик дает нагрузку на контрак и сетевой стек. отфильтровав его в prerouting-raw серверу станет легче.

Comment: psh нужен чтоб понять что в ask есть данные

Comment: @eri как можно отличить вредоносный psh от нормального? в моем вопросе есть скриншот с этим трафиком. там были флаги ask и psh и все пакеты были одинаковые и их были тысячи.. в реальных соединениях флаг psh может встречаться в двух соседних пакетах подряд?

Comment: У нормального должен быть syn, и запись в контраке. Типично делается тцп син ацепт;естаблишед ацепт;тцп дроп

Comment: У вас сервер загружен? Именно сервер, и именно загружен ли, а не тормозит из-за занятого канала. Если значения занятости CPU и LA не запредельно велики, то есть хорошие шансы, что выбрасывание лишних пакетов после их получения сетвой картой сервера ничего особенного не даст.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev когда случаются атаки с трафиком 800Mbit в секунду на хосте полностью пропадает инет. все соединения обрываются по таймауту, как входящие, так и исходящие (с базой и т.п.).
Весь этот атакующий трафик состоит из сплошных пакетов с флагами psh ack.
Что именно от этого нагружается я не знаю, мне не хватает знаний вам ответить. Я даже не знаю, что такое LA

Comment: LA - показатель load average. Вот я и подозреваю, что инет не появится оттого, что сервер, грубо говоря, перестанет им пользоваться в моменты пропадания. Проверить-то, конечно, можно, но вам не я один говорю, что ваша проблема не в перегрузке сервера, а в перегрузке канала.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev перегрузка канала это вы подразумеваете физическую перегрузку на сетевой плате? CPU точно не нагружен. у меня есть его график, там все нормально.

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук на провайдере, на тарифе, на порту свитча. Когда байты на сетевой плате - они туда уже попали. Проблема же вероятнее всего в том, что слишком много байт туда попасть не могут из-за перегрузки.

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук Если CPU точно не нагружен — вы почти точно занимаетесь ерундой. Остаётся простая вилка — либо вам нужен этот проект настолько, что вам требуется нормальная защита от DDoS'ов, либо он вам не настолько нужен. Действия в обоих случаях очевидны.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev CPU точно не загружен. ну знаете, если бы это был tcp syn flood атака, то CPU тоже был бы не загружен, но от нее можно защититься самому. но я понимаю, что это не тот случай. спасибо за ответы, у меня больше нет вопросов